# How do I parse this date format?

Tags: java, date, datetime

How do I parse this date format:

> "Tue Dec 16 07:01:31 CET 2014"

I tried the following:

```
    DateFormat dateformat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL,
            DateFormat.FULL, Locale.CANADA);
```

But that doesn't seem to be correct. Do you recognize this format and know how I need to configure DateFormat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this;

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
Date d = parserSDF.parse("Tue Dec 16 07:01:31 CET 2014");
```

Comment: Yes, with a little edit from me. You need to specify Locale.US (I guess the default one is system-dependent, and my system is not US-eng)